# System configuration in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to setup hadoop multi-node cluster using hadoop version(1.2.1) on two Name-nodes and 4 Data-nodes(8 GB RAM,1 TB HDD,intel core i7 processor). I want to run an application amounting to 100 GB in size(the details of the application are confidential in nature).Can anyone please tell me as to what should be the configuration(same or different?) for the above system to run the application?
I am interested in the hardware considerations of the cluster.
Will these considerations be dependent on the application?
For instance will the hardware required to run an 100 GB wordcount application be different from any other application?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking. Please clarify, what is the application, which parameters you want to configure and what are your options/alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use same configurations to run an application on 100 GB file.